# "You may have..."

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

How would the phrase "You may have..." be translated best in a sentence such as the following?

> **You may have** seen the movie, but you probably didn't *understand* it.

I have done a quick search online, but found nothing.

**Edit:** The sentence means that the person *did* see the movie, but this was not enough to understand it. It's very specific, I know, but I can't see any other way to word it that sounds right.

Comment: Фильм вы хотя и смотрели, но наверняка не поняли.

Comment: Наверняка (in this usage, *бить наверняка* is a whole other beast) refers to a somewhat high probability, but still only a probability.

Comment: ''Наверняка (in this usage, бить наверняка is a whole other beast) refers to a somewhat high probability, but still only a probability.'' - не согласен. wiktionary переводит `наверняка` как `certainly, for sure`.  Словарь Ожегова: "НАВЕРНЯКА(разг.). 1. нареч. Несомненно, обязательно. Приду н. 2. нареч. С верным расчетом, безошибочно. Действовать н. 3. вводн. сл. Конечно, несомненно, разумеется. Он, н; опять опоздает."  Так что Ваш перевод неправилен.

Comment: @user31264 There is a chance I've been using it wrongly all my life, but (1) sounds obsolete to me, especially the example. I'd understand *приду наверняка* as "factors outside my control will likely resolve in a way that enables me to come". And what sets the word apart for me from its "certain" synonyms in (3) is that you only ever use it when making an educated guess, not affirming something you know (*конечно*, *несомненно* or *разумеется* could be either). For what it's worth, I felt that the kind of weak certainty of *наверняка* was a good match for *probably* as used in this sentence.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems you indeed used it wrongly all your life. Wiktionary might be wrong, and my feeling might be wrong (I strongly feel that `наверняка` is same as `for sure`), but they both agree with each other, and they both agree with Ozhegov's dictionary, and all three contradict to your opinion.  Maybe you confused наверняка with наверное, which indeed assumes some kind of weak uncertainty.

Comment: Nikolay Ershov and user31264, I think, that you both are right. The trick is that "наверняка" (and "обязательно" as well, in most cases) is a way to say "for sure" about things which actually no one can ever be sure about: future events or something that you don't (and often can't) see/feel/know exactly by yourself, but still are pretty sure due to some indirect indicators. In such cases all "100% sure" words like "точно", "конечно", "несомненно" and others can also be used, but their meaning is automatically transformed to "for sure with maximum accuracy obtainable in this particular case".

Comment: "Наверняка" and "обязательно" are special because they can be used only when you don't explicitly know the truth. You can't say, for example, "дважды два наверняка равно четырем" or "я сейчас обязательно дома", while the same sentences with other mentioned words are OK.

Comment: My variant is `"Вы хоть и смотрели фильм, но, видимо, не поняли его"`. Here "хоть и" means something like "although" and expresses the idea mentioned in the last edit, and "видимо" stands for "probably" (other variants are, for example, "похоже", "кажется" or something else, but I wouldn't use mentioned above "наверняка" here).

Answer (score 5):

> Возможно/может, вы и смотрели этот фильм, но не поняли его.

Both "might"and "probably " carrying the same meaning of probability and doubt would be expressed by может/возможно.The inversion makes it emphatic with и added.

Comment: I don't think "may have" refers to actual probability/doubt here, rather than to be a way of saying "although you did see the movie..."

Comment: @NikolayErshov You are correct; it is meant to be a way of saying "even though." I think using "you may have" instead gives a different 'feel' to the sentence, as if the other person thought that simply seeing the movie was sufficient, but the speaker says that it was not.

Answer (score 2):

> Фильм вы если и смотрели, вряд ли поняли

This sentence, as much as I can tell without seeing the context, emphasizes the fact the person probably does not understand the movie (regardless of whether or not they have seen it).

The Russian phrase above assumes the reading of "you may or may not have seen the movie, the fact is you likely don't understand it".

Answer (score 0):

`may have` переводится как `могли` (а `probably not` как `вряд ли`).

Вы могли видеть этот фильм, но вряд ли поняли его.

Answer (score 0):

`Должно быть, Вы посмотрели фильм, но, скорее всего, не поняли его`
This is my translation version

Comment: To improve your answer add some comments why you translated the sentence that way.

Comment: I think this means something closer to "You *probably* saw this film [but probably didn't understand it"